# How to get ioctl in c++ to only manage 2 of the 4 buttons my mouse has?

Tags: c++, linux, ioctl

Here is the part of the code:

```
extra_btn_fd = open("/dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_Razer_Naga_2014-event-mouse", O_RDONLY); 

ioctl(extra_btn_fd, EVIOCGRAB, 1);
```

The problem is that it gets control of not only the 2 extra buttons (forward and backward) but also of the click buttons (and scroll I think).

I'm trying to get exclusively the control of the 2 forward and backward buttons and not the clicks.

Comment: Looks like it's an all or nothing deal.

Comment: Well if it is I'd like to know a way to move the mouse directly from c++ without using more cpu than needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to filter events in your code. For example like below

```
while(1) {
  struct input_event event;
  read(extra_btn_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
  if (event.type == EV_KEY && (event.code == BTN_FORWARD || event.code == BTN_BACK) {
    printf("%d %d\n", event.type, event.code);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I already have something similar but the problem is that it either lets the forward and backward buttons do their action while doing my code or do only my code but I can't click/right click/move mouse. To see the full code I suggest you go to : https://github.com/lostallmymoney/Razer_Key_Mapper_Linux/blob/master/src/naga.cpp and look at the "stackoverflow" comment. I want to stop the forward and backward actions but not the others (while detecting backward and forward still).

Comment: If it's not possible to directly ioctl only a part of the inputs I'd like to look forward a way to execute all the keys I'm not filtering out as would linux do normally (like moving the mouse etc)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by xinput by including the 2 buttons in a button map like so :

```
xinput set-button-map $NAGAID2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 11 10 8 9 13 14 15 275 276
```